# How to wrap a long text in table cell (react-bootstrap-table-next)?

Tags: css, react-bootstrap-table

I am introduced to `react/redux/sagas/redux-form` web application development. I used `react-bootstrap-table-next` in order to display data in a table format.

It has `two columns` as `Title`, `Description` however data for `Title` column is a long string data.

```
foo1,foo2,foo3,foo4,foo5,foo6,foo7 bar
```

And the problem I am having is it overflows or occupies cell/row under `Description` so that data under `Description` column is masked.

I tried something like this but it didn't make a difference.

```
const rowStyle = (row, rowIndex) => {
                return { whiteSpace: 'pre-line'; };
};

<BootstrapTable data={ data } columns={ columns } rowStyle={ rowStyle } />
```

What would be the way to wrap this long string so that it can be contained within fixed width of cell under `Title` column?

[update]

Found an answer with following `css` instead.

```
return { overflowWrap: 'break-word' };
```

Comment: Hi Young, should we give some max width to work the answer you mentioned in update? Thank in advance

Comment: hello @Aashiq, unfortunately I am not equipped well to answer your question. I had very brief adventure with react and no longer working on it +2 years.  To be honest I can't remember the exact problem/answer.  All I can say is relying on my original post + update.  My apology not being able to help you on this.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by providing certain styling in your  tag.

```
<BootstrapTable data={data} bodyStyle={ {width: 500, maxWidth: 500, wordBreak: 'break-all' } }>
```

Comment: Aroa, thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately it didn't make a difference, but you expanded my little understanding on applying css on this table.

Comment: @DaeYoung any idea how to do for a particular column? tried?